# Button in Listview doesn't work alertDialog

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

My goal is if I click the `button` in `listview`, and then work `AlertDialog`.
There are no log or error . App is okay even the button is clicked.
On `listview` `onItemClick`, we can make dialog. 
comment please.

I read comment and I show my code. I control `listview` with adapter.

so I have mainActivity.java and listadapter.java I set `listBtnClickListener` in adapter.java and Override in mainActivity.java.

I want to make `AlertBuilder` but It does not work.

main.java

```
    @Override
public void onListBtnClick(final int position, int id) {
    final int pos = position;
    if(adapter.getId(1) == id){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_add, null);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setTitle("add");

        builder.setNegativeButton("cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(400,250);

    }
}
```

adapter.java

```
       @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    callBtnId = 1;
    delBtnId = 3;
    final int pos = position;
    context = parent.getContext();

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(this.resourceId/*R.layout.contact_listview_item*/, parent, false);
    }

    nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    phoneTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    listViewItem = (ListViewItem) getItem(position);

    nameTextView.setText(listViewItem.getName());
    phoneTextView.setText(listViewItem.getPhone());

    Button button1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.callBtn);
    button1.setTag(position);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    callBtnId = button1.getId();

    return convertView;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (this.listBtnClickListener != null) {
        this.listBtnClickListener.onListBtnClick((int) v.getTag(),v.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: Yes, we can comment on this question. But without having your code sample, we can answer it.

Comment: For listview use onItemClickListener

Comment: I change my question.